# android: check if the string not only white spaces

Tags: android, whitespace

How can I check if a string contains anything other than whitespace?
This code didn't work:

```
String string = "   \n\n\t\t     ";
if(string.length()==0) doSomething();
```

since spaces and new lines have values.

Can anyone tell me how can I do it?

**Note**: `minSDKVersion = 5`

Regards :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (string.trim().length() == 0) { /* all white space */ }
```

Alternatively, you can use a regular expression:

```
if (string.matches("\\w*")) { . . . }
```

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
if (string == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(string.trim()) doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `trim` to remove whitespace from both ends of the string. Then compare with the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin:

The below code takes the string, trims all of the letters down, and checks to see if the result is white space by using .isEmpty().

```
val str = " "

if (str.trim().isEmpty()) {
    // white space only
} else {
    // this string has actual characters/letters in it
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Try: it works

```
if (txt.getText().toString().trim().matches(" ")){

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You did not select any text"
                    , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{

}
```